# Expand last child to the bottom of parent

Tags: html, css, alignment, parent

I have one div-container and  children inside it.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div> 
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child" id="last-child"></div>      
</div>
```

I don't know height of children (every time different content), but i have

```
#parent {
   min-height: 500px;
}
```

I want to stretch last-child to the bottom of parent (it has to fill free space from his subling to parent bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this (background colors added for visibility):

```css
#parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #999;
}
.child {
  background: #eee;
}
#last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child" id="last-child">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the parent a flex box with `display:flex;` and the `flex--direction` being `column`. Next give the last child element the `flex:1;` property to make it expand to the remainder of the space in the parent.

```css
#parent {
   min-height: 500px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
#last-child{
  flex:1;
  background:blue;
}
.child{
  background:red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">jljlkj</div>
    <div class="child">kjljlkjl</div> 
    <div class="child">kljlkjlhi</div>
    <div class="child" id="last-child"></div>      
</div>
```

Comment: I wish i could give second right answer. Thank you too.

Comment: You could vote up also...

Comment: I voted up, but I have just registered.